# Put a message from PL/SQL to a JMS Queue running OpenJMS Server

Tags: plsql, jms, advanced-queuing, openjms

I want to put a message out of PL/SQL directly into a running Queue, which runs on the OpenJMS Server.

Is this possible?

I've read the Oracle Advanced Queue section, but I don't really get it. Could you add some code samples or snippets?

Thank you very much!

Regards, flo

Comment: Worst case scenario: you can write a Java stored procedure that implements the messaging and then provide a PL/SQL wrapper for it.

Comment: Sounds acceptable. I'd mark it as correct answer if you want, you'd have to write one ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write an HTTP interface which does the job.